# mysql-connector won't connect

Tags: python, mysql

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='Electronics',
                                         user='pynative',
                                         password='pynative@#29')
    if connection.is_connected():
        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You're connected to database: ", record)

except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

I know this should work because I have the code copied from a website. But for some reason it show s the error

> 'if connection.is_connected():
> NameError: name 'connection' is not defined'

Comment: Which `connection.is_connected()` is raising? It may be your `mysql.connector.connect(...)` raising and then in finally you get `connection is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `mysql.connector.connect` raisesan error, then `connection` variabe is never defined and you can't use it in the finally.

A solution is to initialize it as `None` and check that it isn't none before using it in the `finally`

```py
connection = None
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='Electronics',
                                         user='pynative',
                                         password='pynative@#29')
    if connection.is_connected():
        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You're connected to database: ", record)

except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    if connection and connection.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: Also, If the only thing he is catching is connection error, he can use `else` block to close connection when everything goes ok